# starttime bigger than endtime at inputevent_mv table MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

Way at  inputevent_mv table (MIMIC-III), there are 100 rows were their starttime is bigger than endtime?[image]

SELECT * FROM mimiciii.inputevents_mv where (starttime-endtime)> interval '1 minute'

Answer (score 1):

" Check the columns AMOUNT (all negative) and CANCELREASON (are probably all 1) as well as STATUSDESCRIPTION (Rewritten for those I checked).

https://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/inputevents_mv/#statusdescription

Rewritten - Incorrect information was input, and so the information in this row was rewritten (these rows are primarily useful for auditing purposes - the rates/amounts described were not delivered and so should not be used if determining what compounds a patient has received)."